Regexp for <input> tag
I need restrict values for input tag by only such strings :
1
1,2,3
!2,!3
[1-2]
[1-4],[3-5]
![1-4],![3-5]
1,2,3,[1-4],[3-5]
![1-4],![3-5],1,2,!7

1,2,3..7 are just examples, it may be any digits
My pattern is :
<input type="text"  pattern="(\d*|[\d\-\d,]*|[\!\d]*|[|\[\d-\d\],]*|[\!\[\d\-\d\],]*)"/>

But,for example, this string is also acceptable, but it shouldn't
!!!!!![10-121,444--------,,,,,!!!!----------------,----------]

My question is what is a regexp which accepts only strings above?

ok. you need. but what is the question? do you have errors in your pattern? be more specific.

It looks like you're looking for a sequence of items that are either a number or a range, both possibly preceded by an exclamation mark.
A single item can be represented as follows :
!?(\d|\[\d-\d\])

A sequence of such items is the item, followed by any number of a comma and another occurence of the item, which can be represented as follows :
!?(\d|\[\d-\d\])(,!?(\d|\[\d-\d\]))*

You can try it here.
